# Array isn't persisted to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, devise, parameters

I'm trying to store an array (:vehicles) in my database. This array consists of 3 possible vehicles that the user selects with checkboxes.

```
<% @vehicles.each_with_index do |vehicle,index| %>
    <label>
      <div >
        <%= check_box_tag "vehicles[]", index ,class: "available" ,style: "display:none" %>
        <%= vehicle %>
      </div>
    </label>
<%end %>
```

The ':vehicles' attribute type is 'text' and I used this code to make it an array:

```
serialize :vehicles, Array
```

If I send the params it gets these values in an array.

```
"vehicles"=>["0", "1", "2"],
"commit"=>"Sign up!", 
"controller"=>"registrations", 
"action"=>"create"
```

The problem is that this array isn't stored in the database when I try save it. In the database the code looks like this:

```
vehicles: []
```

Controller code:

```
 def create
    @student = Student.create(student_params)
    if @student.save!
      redirect_to @student
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Student params:

```
def student_params
    params.require(:student).permit(availabilities_attributes: [ :id, :day, :available])
  end
```

Anyone have an idea how to get those values into this array?

Thanks!

Comment: are you permitting the vehicles array attribute in your controller strong parameters?

Comment: Post your create action

Comment: @Ren Yes, 
`def configure_permitted_parameters
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:vehicles]
end`

Comment: @bkunzi01

`def create
    @student = Student.create(student_params)
    if @student.save!
      redirect_to @student
    else
      render :new
    end
  end`

Comment: @crievino , it may help to edit your question showing your controller code and how you're submitting the information from the view.

Comment: Post your student_params method as well.

Comment: please don't post code in comments.  too hard to read.  update your original post instead.

Comment: Your trying to post an array to the column named 'availabilities_attributes'...are you sure the column isn't named vehicles?  If it is just change that to vehicles and you're good to go.

Comment: Why not use an `ARRAY` type column to store this data? Postgres has support for it and it's fantastic.

Comment: for clarification, is `:vehicles` an attribute for users that goes through the Devise controller, or an attribute for `Student`?

Comment: Hi @Ren, actually there is no user table. The Student table is the user table.

Answer (score 0):

In your strong parameters you are going to have to permit the `:vehicles` attribute as an array, like this:  `vehicles: []`

I'm not sure what version of Devise you are using, but drawing from their [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), in the "strong parameters" section, you could permit `vehicles` like this in the application controller:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |student_params|
    student_params.permit({ vehicles: [] }, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

Also if you are using Postgres database, I recommend setting up your `vehicles` attribute to receive an array directly in the database.  You can do so with a migration like this:

```
class AddArrayToStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :students, :vehicles, :string, array: true, default: []
  end
end
```